# How to send batch/mass emails with attachments using mailgun?

Tags: php, laravel, email, email-attachments, mailgun

I want to send batch emails with attachment. I can send the batch emails by attaching the same file to all the emails. But I need to attach different files to different emails by adding file path in recipient variables. I can't see anything related in the official documentation of mailgun.

Here is my code :

```
 # Instantiate the client.
    $mgClient = new Mailgun('key-****');
    $domain = "foo.bar.com";

    # Make the call to the client.
    $result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
        'from'    => 'gido@foo.baar.com',
        'to'      => array('user1@gmail.com', 'user2@gmail.com'),
        'subject' => 'Hi %recipient.first%',
        'text'    => 'Hey there, Just Testing',
        'recipient-variables' => '{"user1@gmail.com": {"first":"User1", "id":1, "file" : "/path/to/file1"},
                                   "user2@gmail.com": {"first":"User2", "id": 2, "file" : "/path/to/file2"}}'
    ), array(
        'attachment' => array('%recipient.file%')
    ));
```

The above code does not work. the attachment array is not able to use recipient variable. Replacing `%recipient.image%` with `/path/to/file` works fine.

Comment: I'm not a Mailgun person, but in the attachment you use `%recipient.image%`, should that be `%recipient.file%` to match what I assume is the field name in the `recipient-variables` list?

Comment: Why do you expect php to know what you mean by '%recipient.image%' ?

Comment: Have seen no doc or code snippet doing that way, can point  to a doc?

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, that was a typing mistake while posting the question. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @MehiShokri Recipient variables can be accessed by `%var%` in batch mailing. You can check the documentation https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#batch-sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per conversation with the Mailgun support team, At this time Mailgun doesn't have a way to assign a specific attachment to each recipient. One thing that can be tried is serving the files on a server and assign the users a URL to retrieve the file from(This is suggested only in case if files are not confidential and stored permanently on the server.).

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/blob/master/doc/attachments.md):

> 'attachment' => [['fileContent'=>$binaryFile,'filename'=>'test.jpg']]

OR

> 'attachment' => [['filePath'=>'/tmp/foo.jpg','filename'=>'test.jpg']]

OR (inline):

> 'inline' => [['filePath'=>'/tmp/foo.jpg', 'filename'=>'test.jpg']]

Comment: The code you shared is not for batch emailing. I want to send different attachments to all the users. The attachments are unique for users.